# Why are copper shower pans nailed to the framing?

Tags: shower, tile

I am in the painful process of re-tiling a shower that started leaking and after removing the tile we found that the pan had many nails through it to the framing. The shower was installed 20 years previously, so obviously these nails had all rusted up badly, although the pan itself was in good shape.

Now am going through the hassle of removing all the nails, which in some cases are nothing but hard mounds of rust and patching all the holes.

Why on God's green earth would they nail the pan to the framing? I mean the thing had 50 pounds of cement and another 20 pounds of tile and the pan was jammed tight into the framing anyway. It's not like it was going to be moving anywhere.

Comment: Maybe they wanted to stabilize the pan when they poured the concrete?

Comment: I usually mail or screw the pan but up at the top lip, to me it would ruin the reason for a pan if they were any place else.

Comment: The shower pan is often nailed or screwed to the wall studs but using common steel nails is not a good idea due to the presence of moisture.  That coupled with the combination of copper and steel is a sure-fire recipe for corrosion.